# Placement new on this

Tags: c++

I saw some code like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(int param);
};

class Derived: public BaseClass
{
};

BaseClass::BaseClass(int param)
{
    new (this) Derived;
}
```

What does the code trying to do? I think it would create a derived class object. However, what is the logic behind? I thought when we call new BaseClass(), it would only allocate memory based on the base class size. However, why could we still pass this pointer to new placement to construct the Derived class object?

Edit:
Thanks for the reply. On further inspection, the code did overwrite  operator new for the base class to allocate memory enough to hold the derived class object and to avoid calling it recursively, in the derived class constructor, it called another base class constructor.

Basically I think it is trying to create something like factory where objects are being created depends on the parameter. Based on the reply, it seems like not a good practise to do so.

Comment: Ew! Wh---ew! That's not good code.

Comment: down that path lies madness, _unless_ of course there [might be a Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CuriouslyRecurringTemplate) involved (that you don't show) -- and even then it smells a lot

Comment: ... besides producing a StackOverflow due to infinite recursion you mean?

Comment: @David: It doesn't even compile (`Derived` has no valid constructor).

Answer (score 11):

That is horrifically undefined behaviour for about six bajillion reasons. Don't ever, ever do it.

Comment: Could you please support your answer with spec/doc/...?

Answer (score 6):

This invokes the constructor of `DerivedClass` on a memory pointed to by `this` pointed. So, the `new` operator doesn't allocate anything, it just calls the constructor to initialize object in a memory that's already allocated.

However, in this particular case the outcome would be very weird at best. You are essentially initializing an object of base class with constructor of derived class. The outcome is that you still have the object of the base class but with state of derived class, or at least pretending that is has such state. Depending on whether derived class introduces some new fields which its constructor refers to, this might even result in memory access violation...

So, short advice: don't do that. In general, don't use *placement new* at all unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong in that code. For starters, to pick on the trivial one, the constructor should not be qualified inside the class declaration.

The next thing is what it looks like it is doing: It looks like it is creating an object of type `Derived` in the memory allocated for `Base`.

- The problems here include the fact that `Derived` might require more memory than `Base`, and there is no guarantee that the memory is available.
- It will trigger an infinite recursion loop, as the constructor of `Base` is trying to create a `Derived`, that will in turn try to call the constructor of `Base`, which will try to create a `Derived`...
- Even if the recursion is cut (provide an alternative `Base` constructor, and have the called `Derived` constructor dispatch to that non-recurring version), and `Derived` fits in the memory footprint of `Base`, any member of `Base` that has already been initialized would be *reinitialized* invoking undefined behavior. For example, if `Base` contained an attribute that allocates and manages memory internally, its constructor would be called twice leaking the resources acquired in the first call. Respectively, the number of objects constructed and destructed would not match.
- probably many other issues up to the *six bajillion* number that DeadMG mentions.

Answer (score 0):

That's undefined behavior, it will likely recursively call base class constructor and you'll get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile.

No constructor is defined for `Derived` and the compiler cannot generate a default constructor because `Base` has only one constructor which requires an argument.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no logic behind this. By the way in C++ when you build a derived instance the object is first initialized as a base (i.e. the constructor for base is executed first). Therefore I'd say that this code will just call recursively itself forever (until the stack space is exhausted, that is).